# PyKafka client connecting wrong broker

Tags: apache-kafka, pykafka

I am unable to figure out what's happening.

I started producer by running the command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

and consumer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

But when I do

```
client = KafkaClient('localhost:9092')
```

It always says:
`Failed to connect newly created broker for b'adnans-mbp':9092`

```
Error encountered when producing to broker b'adnans-mbp':9092. Retrying.
Error encountered when producing to broker b'adnans-mbp':9092. Retrying.
```

On sending messages I get nothing in program. Although on console it's receiving messages.

What's wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `listeners` property in the `server.properties` config file. It looks like your `KafkaClient` instance is unable to communicate with the broker you're running locally, possibly due to the hostname translation that's turning `localhost` into `adnans-mbp`.

See also https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/812